# Make and build utilities on CentOS/RHEL?

Tags: build, centos, utilities, rhel

I've been unsuccessfully searching for a way to install `make` utility on my CentOS 5.2. I've looked through some RPM repositories and online, with no avail. Installing `gcc`, `gcc-c++` didn't help! Package `build-essential` is not made for CentOS/RHEL. I have RPMFORGE repo enabled in YUM.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just double checked and CentOS 5.2 already includes make!

I found it also in one of the online mirrors, if it is easier for you:

http://centos.cogentcloud.com/5.2/os/i386/CentOS/make-3.81-3.el5.i386.rpm

if you installed the 64 bit version:

http://centos.cogentcloud.com/5.2/os/x86_64/CentOS/make-3.81-3.el5.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Thanks, this worked. My Slicehost account includes a barebone install of CentOS, nothing but the raw OS...

Answer (score 86):

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

or

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
```

Comment: The second method doesn't install make

Answer (score 38):

```
yum install make
```

also works.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need this if groupinstall doesn't work:

`yum install -y gcc-c++ make`

Answer (score 1):

This command works for me

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
```